# MVC application hosted ON IIS for windows authentication mode not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7, windows-authentication

How to setup windows authentication on IIS.

I have added following lines in appkeys in web.config:

```
   <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
   <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />


 <authentication mode="Windows">
</authentication>

<authorization>
   <deny users="?/>
</authorization>
```

above all working fine on development environment. But, when hosted on IIS and also set windows authention mode enable in IIS.

Then, its just gicing me errir `401 nOT AUTHORIZE ERROR.`

If I remove deny user then, not able to get Http context user name and application not working.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

I just needed to disable anonomous authenticaiton in IIS. In addition to above all settings.

So, IIS - enable windows authentcaiton and disable anonomous authentication and apply settings that mentioned in above question.

Thanks